# Redirecting a Website request with multiple embedded URL strings

Tags: f5, irule

I need to redirect the following example to a new website URL.
https://test.test.com/MDR/LauncherInterface.aspx?host=https://test.test.com/MDR&numid=11111&numid=1111&username=1111&userpass=1111

I need to redirect both URL statements to https://test2.test.com.  Using iRules in my F5 load balancer I am able to redirect the first statement but I am unable to figure out how to redirect the second as well.

Answer (score 0):

something like this should help:

```
when HTTP_REQUEST {
  if { [HTTP::host] eq "test.test.com" } {
    HTTP::redirect https://test2.test.com[HTTP::uri]
  }
}
```

You can also do this with a local traffic policy, and if the rule is really this simple, that would be the preferred approach as it would be more performant. See [this article on DevCentral](https://devcentral.f5.com/s/articles/to-irule-or-not-to-irule-introduction-to-local-traffic-policies-20384) for details on choosing iRules versus local traffic policy.

Finally, known that using the [HTTP::redirect](https://clouddocs.f5.com/api/irules/HTTP__redirect.html) command, you'll be restricted to a 302. Use [HTTP::respond](https://clouddocs.f5.com/api/irules/HTTP__respond.html) to change the redirect code.